# iframe中のHTMLに文字コードを指定するには？

Tags: html5

iframe中にAmazonから取得したHTMLを埋め込んで表示させようとしていますが、時々文字化けします。こちら側のHTMLはmetaタグでUTF-8指定、Amazonが返すHTMLもUTF-8のようですが、charsetのmetaタグがないせいか、Chromeでは数回に一度の割で文字化けを起こします。古いIEでは問題ありません。

処理は、こちらのHTML中に以下のようにPHPで取得しています。

```
<iframe src="取得スクリプト.php" ...>
```

[取得スクリプト.php]

```
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

取得スクリプト中で、取得したHTMLにmetaタグを埋め込んで返すことは可能かと思いますが、何か他に回避策があればご教示ください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [できないと思います。](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iframeの中の`charset`を現在のページから継承してくれればいいのですが、Chromeはそうではないようですね。`iframe`は、本来完結したHTML文書を埋め込むものなので、`iframe`の中に`charset`がないので自動識別して間違ったエンコーディングになっているように思います。それであれば、`iframe`を使うのであれば、metaタグを埋め込むしかないでしょう。

`取得スクリプト.php`の内容が、CSS等を含まないボディ部分のHTML要素であれば、`iframe`にするのではなくて、jQueryの`.load()`を使ってHTML要素を挿入した方がいいと思います。

```
$("#result").load("取得スクリプト.php");
```

Comment: 取得したHTMLにはCSSとJavaScriptが大量に含まれていますが、決まりきったことなので、それらをファイルに保存しておいて、<body>の中身をこちらのHTMLに注入することにしました。ありがとうございました。